# BR tag in HTML but not in JSP

Tags: html, jsp

I'm trying to figure out why I have a blank space on my web page. When I inspect the page and view the HTML elements I noticed two `<br>` elements. I thought to myself, "Great, now I can edit the JSP file and remove the two `<br>` tags." They are nowhere to be found! What am I missing here?

HTML:

[image: HTML screenshot]

JSP:

[image: JSP screenshot]

I'm going crazy trying to figure this out, thanks in advance for your help. And please let me know if you need more info from me.

Comment: https://www.wondercms.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=596 it may helps you.

Comment: @RahulDudharejiya, Thanks for commenting, but running my JSP file through an HTML minifier sounds like it would cause more harm than good. And there is so much code in this table, that I cannot try to mimic what a minifier would do.